# Setting current page menu as active

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I downloaded menu from:

```
http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropline_2.html
```

And used in my application.

But when I am clicking on a menu it is not highlighting as active menu.
That means i want give an active class to a menu which i clicked .
How can i do this by using this menu code.

My application is in php.

Comment: might be a good thing if you can provide us with the codes in the document so we can have a better view of the situation.

Comment: Without seeing any code, you could always do it manually in CSS, .element:hover { /* Active css */ }

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using the dirname function or **FILE** global variable to get the file name/path. Thereby, being able to find which tab should be highlighted.

Imagine this directory tree

html_root/

- video/

  - file.php
- music/

  - anotherfile.php

...

Say that each tab is organized into its own directory.

Inside your header file

```
<?php
if (dirname(__FILE__) == "video") {
  // Set css to video tab
} // etc.
?>
```